# Who are some people (or well-known fictional characters) that drew a lot of media attention in 18th/19th century Europe/US?

Tags: cultural-history, social-history

Suppose someone is suddenly exposed to a barrage of media attention today, they might say something like "I feel like a Kardashian".

What if I have a character (in Europe) experiencing something similar in the 1850s, who are some of the analogous public figures that they might reference - "I feel like ____"?

Comment: Given the vast differences between the media in 1850 and that of today, would there have been a similar "barrage of media attention" in 1850?

Comment: Louis Pasteur’s vaccine bet with Rossingol, and the resulting demonstration, for instance, was widely reported on in the press and received heavy media coverage

Comment: [Beau Brummel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beau_Brummell), [Oscar Wilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Wilde) and [Sarah Bernhardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah_Bernhardt) all come to mind. What research have you done?